# onnxruntime: Given model could not be parsed while creating inference session. Error message: Protobuf parsing failed

Tags: tensorflow, classification, tensorflow-lite, onnx, onnxruntime

According to the example code mentioned below the library. I have followed the example  code but it didn't work.

[Library] https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/

**Code**

```
from nudenet import NudeClassifier
import onnxruntime
classifier = NudeClassifier()

classifier.classify('/home/coremax/Downloads/DETECTOR_AUTO_GENERATED_DATA/IMAGES/3FEF7B75-3823-4153-8490-87483AAC6ABC'
                    '.jpg')
```

I have also followed the previous solution on StackOverflow but it didn't work
[Error on running Super Resolution Model from ONNX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273951/error-on-running-super-resolution-model-from-onnx)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/276/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/276/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/coremax/Documents/NudeNet/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    classifier = NudeClassifier()
  File "/home/coremax/Documents/NudeNet/nudenet/classifier.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.nsfw_model = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_path)
  File "/home/coremax/anaconda3/envs/AdultNET/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/session.py", line 158, in __init__
    self._load_model(providers or [])
  File "/home/coremax/anaconda3/envs/AdultNET/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/session.py", line 166, in _load_model
    True)
RuntimeError: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/inference_session.cc:238 onnxruntime::InferenceSession::InferenceSession(const onnxruntime::SessionOptions&, const onnxruntime::Environment&, const string&) status.IsOK() was false. Given model could not be parsed while creating inference session. Error message: Protobuf parsing failed.
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Still, I haven't get any solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NSFW detection module nudenet not longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696761/python-nsfw-detection-module-nudenet-not-longer-working)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but hope this helps someone build a very useful software.

## why it fails

the error is that for NudeClassifier to work it has to download the onnx model from this [link](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_model.onnx)

but github now requires you to be logged in to download any file so the constructor for the NudeClassifier fails as it tries to download this model

## Solution

1. create a folder in your user's home folder with the name `.NudeNet/`
2. download the model from this [link](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_model.onnx)
3. save the model in the folder you created in step one
4. you should now have the model at the following path `~/.NudeNet/classifier_model.onnx`

now you're ready to go good luck!